# Changing SVG elements using d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, d3.js

I want to change SVG somen element attibutes using d3. Actually I will be downloading via AJAX from server data that will change SVG element colors based on data values.

Here is my piece of code to change SVG element graphical behaviour:

SVG EXAMPLE FILE:

```
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect id="box1" height="54" width="106" y="73" x="53" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
  <ellipse ry="39" rx="41" id="circle1" cy="103" cx="246" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
  <path id="multiline1" d="m395,105l70,10c0,0 11,63 11,64c0,1 -3,60 -9,61c-6,1 -75,1 -79,1c-4,0 -43,-16 -42,-25c1,-9 -4,-29 1,-42c5,-13 14,-57 14,-58" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

HTML Code:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/d3-master/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<object id="svgobject" type="image/svg+xml" data=".\svg\mainscreen.svg">
</object>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var element = d3.selectAll("svgobject");
    var item = element.property("box1");
    item.style("color", "blue");

</script>
```

I´m using VS2012, ASP.NET with Razor.

The browser (Chome) says on console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'box1' of null

I have tried different approaches with no success.

**[EDIT]**

Working Code (had to forget d3 for a while):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var mySvg = document.getElementById("svgobject");
    alert(mySvg);
    mySvg.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var svg = mySvg.getSVGDocument();
        alert(svg);
        svg.getElementById("box1").setAttribute("fill", "green");
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried `d3.select("rect").style("fill", "blue");`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit the first 2 lines of your js and simply use:

```
var item = d3.select("#box1")
item.style("fill", "blue");
```

Or, in one line, as Lars suggested:

```
d3.select("#box1").style("fill", "blue");
```

Since you're selecting a SVG element you have to use the `fill` property instead of `color` which is used for html.

[Here is the fiddle with the update code.](http://jsfiddle.net/XjGzq/2/)

Comment: Not working at all on my environment: VS2012, ASP.NET, MVC4, Razor. I have a _Layout file that adds menu and content-wrapper. Strange. No errors on Chrome console now...

Comment: Maybe there is something else causing the problem? Does your AJAX request return anything?

Comment: I had created a blank project in VS and added just this code. Chome shows no error, but does not change color. On IE, not changing colors and I got that message: Unhandled exception at line 24, column 5 in http://localhost:7408/Scripts/d3-master/d3.js

0x800a138f - Cannot get 'prototype' property value: The object is null or not verified (translated).

Comment: Piece of d3 code with error:try {
    d3_document.createElement("div").style.setProperty("opacity", 0, "");
  } catch (error) {
==>    var d3_element_prototype = d3_window.Element.prototype, d3_element_setAttribute = d3_element_prototype.setAttribute, d3_element_setAttributeNS = d3_element_prototype.setAttributeNS, d3_style_prototype = d3_window.CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype, d3_style_setProperty = d3_style_prototype.setProperty;